# Wpdb Data Insert with Ajax

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert

I am trying to enter insert data with form in wordpress and want to use ajax for that. Without ajax it works fine but when I use ajax pressing the submit button gives 0 in result and the data is not inserted to the database. Below is my code.

Html code is between form tags as below:

```
<form id="insert_form" action="" method="post">
  <input id="user" style="height: 30px;" name="user" type="text" />
  .
  .
  .
  <button id="submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
function wp_insert() {
  if(isset($_POST['skillname'])!= '' && $_POST['Address']!= '') {
    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
    $username=$user_info->user_login;

    // insert to database

    if($_POST['Submit']) {
      // run validation if you are not doing it in JS
      global $wpdb;

      // assigning textbox values to variables

      $yourname = $_POST['user'];
      $lat = $_POST['latitude'];
      $long = $_POST['longitude'];
      $address = $_POST['Address'];
      $city = $_POST['City'];
      $state = $_POST['State'];
      $country = $_POST['Country'];
      $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
      $skillname = $_POST['skillname'];
      $yourself = $_POST['yourself'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];


      if($wpdb->insert('wp_store_locator',
        array(
          'secretcode' => $username,
          'sl_description' => $yourname,
          'sl_latitude' => $lat,
          'sl_longitude' => $long,
          'sl_address' => $address,
          'sl_city' => $city,
          'sl_state' => $state,
          'sl_country' => $country,
          'sl_zip' => $zip,
          'sl_store' => $skillname,
          'yourself' => $yourself,
          'sl_email' => $email,
          'sl_phone' => $phone )) == false) 
          wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); 
        else
          echo 'Database insertion successful'; 

        exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Enqueue code for jQuery:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_insert' ); 

function add_insert() {
  add_action('wp_ajax_wp_insert', 'wp_insert');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_insert', 'wp_insert');

  // register & enqueue a javascript file called globals.js
  wp_register_script('globalss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/ajaxinsert.js", array('jquery')); 
  wp_enqueue_script('globalss');

  // use wp_localize_script to pass PHP variables into javascript
  wp_localize_script('globalss', 'yess', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}
```

jQuery File ajaxInsert.js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $("#insert_form").submit(function (e) { // form is intercepted
    e.preventDefault();

    // serialize the form which contains secret_code
    var sentData = $(this).serializeArray();

    // Add the additional param to the data        
    sentData.push({
      name: 'action',
      value: 'wp_insert'
    })

    // set sentData as the data to be sent
    $.post(yess.ajaxurl, sentData, function (rez) {
      alert(rez);
      return false;
    },
    'html'); //set the dataType as json, so you will get the parsed data in the callback
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is the right name of your submit button? If($_POST['Submit'])

Comment: Try changing the id of the submit button so it's not `Submit` make it `formSubmit` or something. I have found that submit buttons with an ID of `submit` can sometimes cause errors.

Comment: Wordpress has wp_ajax hook take a look at this answer it will give you idea how you can use ajax in wordpress http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022456/how-to-receive-data-from-database-via-jquery-wordpress-js/28022806#28022806

Comment: Thanks everybody my problem is solved I had to change the below line ... below is the corrected version ... thanks everybody who helped me thanks                                                                add_action( 'wp_ajax_insertfunction', 'insertfunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_insertfunction', 'insertfunction');